# datatables server side processing sql server with custom data

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, datatables

I have a big database of ~120k records and I have written an application to interact with its data, with a part to edit them which I have to improve because I'm getting data from dialogs and it should be better if I do inline. This application is made with jQuery - jQueryUI - Datatables.

As workaround to avoid the big queries in the main selection, I have reduced the chance to give a lot of data. The server is a Windows 2008 R2 on which runs an instance of IIS with the module PHP, this module at the beginning was configured to run with 256MB of memory, I have switched to 512MB because of memory bottleneck but I was still having bottleneck on the memory. Measuring it I noticed in some queries it need more memory, about ~600MB, for this reason I left with memory_limit -1, so limitless.

Actually the PHP middleware returns the resultset as JSON, it makes a conversion which needs double the amount of memory.
I apologize if I dwell in explanations off the subject, I do just to take the point of my work.
Btw I didn't have time to study a solution when I wrote the application, but now I have.
Now came the point, SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't implement the limits in query selection.
First of all I made a query with limits in sql server:
https://pastebin.com/8JZTAerE

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 10, @PageNumber INT = 1
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        myview.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY foo) AS RowNum
    FROM myview WHERE 1=1
     -- AND foo AND bar AND baz
    ) AS BDT
WHERE
    BDT.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
    AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)
```

To make this query work, me or DataTables have to pass some parameter more, such as RowsPerPage, PageNumber, the sorting criteria and the filtering string which allows you to do a second skimming to the resultset returned. It's like a second because you can specify in a second moment after you made the main query. Also this one should be studied, because some example do this filtering on every field of the table, but of course DataTable has two types of filtering on the resultset: the global which works on every field and the local which works on a single field, so the query should be more sophisticated and take two sections of filtering. But this one in a pure SQL problem, PHP and DataTable shouldn't care.

How to do this? In every example I found, nobody specified the data in ajax call. I thought DataTables give this into the post array, but I need to specify because I must pass my parameters.

This is my ajax call:

```
function ajax_search() {
  
    return $.ajax({

        beforeSend: function(event, ui) {
            $('#contents').html('<h2>' + title + ' <img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="Loading..."></h2>');
        },

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'json/ricerca_bdt_ssp.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'user': account,
            'pass': password,
            'user_ad': account_ad,
            'pass_ad': password_ad,
            'device': deviceid,
            'host': dbhost,
            'port': dbport,
            'db': dbname,
            'foo': field_foo,
            'bar': field_bar,
            'baz': field_baz,
            ...
            'other_field': bdt_other_fields,
            'other_pattern': bdt_other_pattern
        }

    });

};
```

My DataTables definition (plus some other config on tooltip and checkbox sorting):

```
table = $("#mytable").DataTable({
    buttons: [ one,two,three ],
    aoColumnDefs: [
        { 'sWidth': '150px', 'aTargets': [1,2,7,8,12,13,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,24] },
        ....
    ],
    select: { style: 'multi', selector: 'td:first-child' },

    'autoWidth': false,

    iDisplayLength: 100,
    'scrollY': '50vh',
    'scrollX': 'true',
    'scrollCollapse': 'true'
});
```

My DataTables definition is not more be upgraded to the server side pagination, I will add  "bProcessing": true and "serverSide": true.

Thank you very very much in advance

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Excuse me, to describe the situation I did not make the question clear.

Comment: I was wondering how to pass the parameters you need to DataTables for the server side pagination. From the query there are some other parameter which are needed for the query but which I don't know how see and pass to the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use server side you should do the following:

```
//...
serverSide: true,
ajax: {
    url: "json/ricerca_bdt_ssp.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: function (d) {
        d.user = account;
        d.pass = password;
        //...
        d.other_field = bdt_other_fields;
        d.other_pattern = bdt_other_pattern;
    }
//...
```

`d` is an object containing all the required [parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for paging, in particular `start`and `length`. You can expand `d` as shown.

then you have to format the returned json as specified in the link.

Comment: Thank you man, it works and was what I need. Now I just need end up the middleware resource.